# Create custom function for upload and insert data

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Is there any chance that I can create a custom function for upload? I have 2 function which are insert_content() and insert_officials. In that function there is a code for uploading image. How will I do that since they have the same code of config.

```php
public function insert_content() {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

        $name        = array('post_title','post_category','post_description');
        $label       = array('Title','Category','Description');
        $verify      = 'trim|required';
        $this->validate($name[0], $label[0], $verify);
        $this->validate($name[1], $label[1], $verify);
        $this->validate($name[2], $label[2], $verify);
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">', '</p>');

        if($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $data['success'] = true;
        } else {
            foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
                $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit;
        }

        $date = date('Y');
        $month = date('m');
        $upload_config = array (
           'upload_path'  => './assets/uploads/'.$date.'/'.$month, 'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|jpeg',
           'max_size'     => '2048', 'max_width'    => '1536', 'max_height'   => '1024'
        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $upload_config);

        if(!is_dir($upload_config['upload_path'])) {
            mkdir($upload_config['upload_path'], 0777, TRUE);
        }

        if($this->upload->do_upload('post_image')) {    
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $image = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];

            $data = array (
                $name[0] => $this->pass($name[0]),
                $name[1] => $this->pass($name[1]),
                $name[2] => $this->pass($name[2]),
                'post_image' => $image
            );
            $this->model->CreateContent($data);
        }
    }

    //Officials
    public function insert_officials() {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

        $name   = array('official_fname','official_mname','official_lname','official_nickname','official_contact','official_position','official_barangay','official_address');
        $label  = array('First Name','Middle Name','Last Name','Nickname','Contact','Position','Barangay','Address');
        $verify = 'trim|required';
        $number = 'required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{11}$/]';
        $this->validate($name[0], $label[0], $verify);
        $this->validate($name[1], $label[1], $verify);
        $this->validate($name[2], $label[2], $verify);
        $this->validate($name[3], $label[3], $verify);
        $this->validate($name[4], $label[4], $number);
        $this->validate($name[5], $label[5], $verify);
        $this->validate($name[6], $label[6], $verify);
        $this->validate($name[7], $label[7], $verify);
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">', '</p>');

        if($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $data['success'] = true;
        } else {
            foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
                $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit;
        }

        $date = date('Y');
        $month = date('m');
        $upload_config = array (
           'upload_path'  => './assets/uploads/'.$date.'/'.$month, 'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|jpeg',
           'max_size'     => '2048', 'max_width'    => '2048', 'max_height'   => '1024'
        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $upload_config);

        if(!is_dir($upload_config['upload_path'])) {
            mkdir($upload_config['upload_path'], 0777, true);
        }

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('official_image')) {    
            $data = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors('<span class="ti-remove"></span> '));
            
        } else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $image = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];

            $data = array (
                $name[0] => $this->pass($name[0]),
                $name[1] => $this->pass($name[1]),
                $name[2] => $this->pass($name[2]),
                $name[3] => $this->pass($name[3]),
                $name[4] => $this->pass($name[4]),
                $name[5] => $this->pass($name[5]),
                $name[6] => $this->pass($name[6]),
                $name[7] => $this->pass($name[7]),
                'official_image' => $image
            );

            $this->model->CreateOfficials($data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a function and put it in a model or something:

```
function upload($fieldname);
    $date = date('Y');
    $month = date('m');
    $upload_config = array (
       'upload_path'  => './assets/uploads/'.$date.'/'.$month, 'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|jpeg',
       'max_size'     => '2048', 'max_width'    => '1536', 'max_height'   => '1024'
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $upload_config);

    if(!is_dir($upload_config['upload_path'])) {
        mkdir($upload_config['upload_path'], 0777, TRUE);
    }

    if($this->upload->do_upload($fieldname)) {
        return $this->upload->data();
    }  
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
$this->load->model('somemodel');
$imageup = $this->somemodel->upload('post_image');
if ($imageup) {
    // image uploaded succesfully
    echo $imageup['file_name'];
} else {
    // upload failed
    // you should be able to also access error
    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
}
```

Comment: I want to insert the data and also the filename of the image.

Comment: its pretty self-explanatory. put it in the if condition

Comment: You mean like this? if($imageup) { //code for insert } else { }

Comment: yes, and you can access the filename as I've shown you

Comment: These what I did. I don't know if it is correct. Can you check it, please? https://ibb.co/iJOWvp https://ibb.co/dkS8ap

Comment: Got it. Thank you brother!

Comment: I put the function upload in the controller. Is it okay, right?

Comment: you can do that. just mark it as `private` instead of `public` although it is better to put it in a model - it isn't required